# Local Storage icons in IPhone DCIM folder

Tags: ios, iphone, local-storage

When I plug my IPhone (6 Plus) to my Windows computer, I see some "Local Storage" (named in Turkish "Yerel Disk") icons in DCIM folder. Any idea what are these, could it be viruses??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a possible answer.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6585223?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

- I have the same problem. And I didn't remember my photos were altered (cropped, photo filters applied, etc.) at all.
- For the solution of removing those mystery files:

  1. Disconnect IPhone with Windows machine
  2. Settings --> Safari --> Clear History and Website Data
  3. reconnect IPhone with Windows machine, double check DCIM and subfolders.
     Then they disappear.

*** The above solution works for me. But the solution makes those files even more mystery. Why deleting Safari related Data (I assume "Clear History and Website Data" does the function as it described) could clean files inside DCIM ? ( Another assumption: files inside DCIM are photos related. Actually not sure)

- The only technical details I find is a comment in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6585223?start=15&tstart=0

"""

Lawrence Finch
Mar 14, 2015 5:39 PM 
Re: Windows explorer see's multiple "Local Disk" files in the iphone DCIM folders
in response to CrazyRoadBiker
CrazyRoadBiker wrote:

(PS - I managed to look inside of some of the "local disk" files and they seem to contain a modified XML structure.  Why Apple doesn't just put an XML file in the folder that is standard and able to be recognized by Windows, I have no idea. . .)

The metatdata files are a standard image metadata format (.AAE), and Windows understands it. But you have to use the Camera and Scanner wizard to import the images. It understands those files, but Windows Explorer does not.
"""

So...